# Dataflow job has this values as temp_location "gs://dataflow-staging-us-east1-657091687220/temp" instead of what I set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I created the template like this:

```
python main.py --project PROJECT_NAME--staging_location gs://BUCKETNAME/dataflow/staging  --temp_location gs://BUCKETNAME/temp --template_location gs://BUCKETNAME/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME --machine_type  n1-custom-2-13312  --runner DataflowRunner --max_num_workers 36 --no_use_public_ips  --job_name JOBNAME --region us-east1
```

and then I launch it like this:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run DFLOWJOBNAME --gcs-location gs://BUCKETNAME/dataflow/templates/qtest --parameters INPUT_AND_OUTPUTFILESPARAMS  --region us-east1
```

The job runs ok, until the end, then it fails reading some avro file inside this misterious gs://dataflow-staging-us-east1-657091687220/temp.

In the web ui I see it is set as temp location: [image]

At the end of this question lies the output of `gcloud dataflow jobs show JOB_ID --environment`
and I can see that there are 2 fields containing the unkown gcp bucket in the title, namely: "tempStoragePrefix" and "gcpTempLocation".

I don't really care about the tmp folder, I just want the job to complete

```
creationTime: '2020-01-28 13:00:19'
environment:
  clusterManagerApiService: instancegroup.googleapis.com
  dataset: bigquery.googleapis.com/cloud_dataflow
  experiments:
  - emit_autoscaling_rationales
  - emit_autoscaling_monitoring_events
  - enable_billing_v_1_5
  - use_cloud_gaia
  - enable_dataflow_service_account
  - enable_dataprep_new_billing
  - delayed_launch
  - enable_component_new_persistence_format_wave4
  - enable_throttled_based_rescaling
  - use_grpc_shuffle_appliance_transport
  - use_replica_pools
  - limit_preemptible_worker_pct
  - limit_resizing_by_cpu_util
  - override_controller_service_account
  - use_shuffle_service_dynamic_repartitioning
  - shuffle_service_repartition_hotkey_detection_fraction=0.8
  - enable_shuffle_service_new_billing
  - enable_shuffle_service_throttled_proxy_based_scaling
  - use_dataflow_service_account_in_igm
  - use_fixed_costs_in_resizing
  - use_gci_image
  - use_host_networking
  - use_multi_hop_delegation
  - use_new_tmp_filename_format
  - use_process_pool_config
  - use_work_manager_v2
  - use_worker_zone_chooser_by_default
  - worker-translation
  - use_fastavro
  sdkPipelineOptions:
    display_data:
    - key: runner
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: DataflowRunner
    - key: project
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: PROJECT_NAME
    - key: job_name
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176
    - key: staging_location
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259
    - key: temp_location
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: gs://TMPBUCKET/temp/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259
    - key: region
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: us-east1
    - key: template_location
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME
    - key: max_num_workers
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: INTEGER
      value: 36
    - key: machine_type
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: n1-custom-2-13312
    - key: use_public_ips
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: BOOLEAN
      value: false
    - key: experiments
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: "['use_fastavro']"
    - key: beam_plugins
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: "['apache_beam.io.filesystem.FileSystem', 'apache_beam.io.hadoopfilesystem.HadoopFileSystem',\
        \ 'apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.LocalFileSystem', 'apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem']"
    - key: save_main_session
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: BOOLEAN
      value: true
    - key: input
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: None)'
    - key: output
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: output, type: str, default_value: None)'
    - key: data4
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: data4, type: str, default_value: None)'
    - key: data3
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: data3, type: str, default_value:
        None)'
    - key: data2
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: data2, type: str, default_value: None)'
    - key: data1
      namespace: apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions
      type: STRING
      value: 'RuntimeValueProvider(option: data1, type: str, default_value:
        None)'
    - key: templateLocation
      namespace: google.dataflow.v1beta3.TemplatesService
      type: STRING
      value: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME
    options:
      data3: null
      data2: null
      beam_plugins:
      - apache_beam.io.filesystem.FileSystem
      - apache_beam.io.hadoopfilesystem.HadoopFileSystem
      - apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.LocalFileSystem
      - apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem
      dataflow_endpoint: https://dataflow.googleapis.com
      direct_num_workers: 1
      direct_runner_bundle_repeat: 0
      direct_runner_use_stacked_bundle: true
      dry_run: false
      enable_streaming_engine: false
      environment_cache_millis: 0
      experiments:
      - use_fastavro
      input: null
      job_name: beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176
      machine_type: n1-custom-2-13312
      data1: null
      max_num_workers: 36
      no_auth: false
      output: null
      pipelineUrl: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/pipeline.pb
      pipeline_type_check: true
      profile_cpu: false
      profile_memory: false
      profile_sample_rate: 1
      project: PROJECT_NAME
      data4: null
      region: us-east1
      runner: DataflowRunner
      runtime_type_check: false
      save_main_session: true
      sdk_location: default
      sdk_worker_parallelism: 0
      staging_location: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259
      streaming: false
      temp_location: gs://TMPBUCKET/temp/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259
      templateLocation: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME
      template_location: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME
      type_check_strictness: DEFAULT_TO_ANY
      update: false
      use_public_ips: false
  tempStoragePrefix: storage.googleapis.com/dataflow-staging-us-east1-657091687220/temp
  userAgent:
    name: Apache Beam Python 3.6 SDK
    version: 2.16.0
  version:
    job_type: PYTHON_BATCH
    major: '7'
  workerPools:
  - autoscalingSettings:
      algorithm: AUTOSCALING_ALGORITHM_BASIC
      maxNumWorkers: 36
    diskSizeGb: 250
    diskSourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/dataflow-service-producer-prod/global/images/dataflow-dataflow-owned-resource-20200109-14-rc00
    diskType: compute.googleapis.com/projects//zones//disks/pd-standard
    ipConfiguration: WORKER_IP_PRIVATE
    kind: harness
    machineType: n1-custom-2-13312
    metadata:
      cloud_region: us-east1
      cos-update-strategy: update_disabled
      dataflow_api_endpoint: https://dataflow.googleapis.com/
      enable_jvm_metrics: 'false'
      google-container-manifest: |
        {
          "apiVersion": "v1",
          "kind": "Pod",
          "metadata": {
            "name": "dataflow"
          },
          "spec": {
            "containers": [ {
              "args": [ "--log_file=/var/log/dataflow/boot-json.log", "--log_dir=/var/log/dataflow", "--work_dir=/var/opt/google/dataflow", "--tmp_dir=/var/opt/google/tmp", "--endpoint=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/" ],
              "image": "gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python36:2.16.0",
              "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
              "name": "python",
              "volumeMounts": [ {
                "mountPath": "/opt/google/dataflow/libshuffle_v1.so",
                "name": "shuffle-lib-v1-python"
              }, {
                "mountPath": "/opt/google/dataflow/libshuffle_v1_py3.so",
                "name": "shuffle-lib-v1-python3"
              }, {
                "mountPath": "/var/opt/google",
                "name": "persist"
              }, {
                "mountPath": "/var/log/dataflow",
                "name": "dataflowlogs-harness"
              } ]
            }, {
              "args": [ "--log_file=/var/log/dataflow/boot-json.log", "--log_dir=/var/log/dataflow", "--physmem_limit_pct=30", "--sorter_size=134217728", "--port=12345", "--grpc_port=12346", "--status_port=22349", "--db_path=/var/shuffle" ],
              "image": "dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/shuffle:20200109-14-rc00",
              "imagePullPolicy": "Never",
              "name": "shuffle",
              "ports": [ {
                "containerPort": 12345,
                "hostPort": 12345,
                "name": "sh-data-port"
              }, {
                "containerPort": 12346,
                "hostPort": 12346,
                "name": "sh-grpc-port"
              }, {
                "containerPort": 22349,
                "hostPort": 22349,
                "name": "sh-status-port"
              } ],
              "volumeMounts": [ {
                "mountPath": "/var/shuffle",
                "name": "dataflow-shuffle"
              }, {
                "mountPath": "/var/log/dataflow",
                "name": "dataflowlogs-shuffle"
              } ]
            }, {
              "args": [ "--teardown_interval=10m", "--log_file=/var/log/dataflow/vm_monitor-json.log", "--dataflow_base_path=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/", "--region=us-east1", "--teardown_policy=TEARDOWN_ALWAYS" ],
              "image": "dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/vmmonitor:20200109-14-rc00",
              "imagePullPolicy": "Never",
              "name": "vmmonitor",
              "volumeMounts": [ {
                "mountPath": "/var/log/dataflow",
                "name": "dataflowlogs-vmmonitor"
              } ]
            }, {
              "args": [ "--log_file=/var/log/dataflow/health_checker-json.log", "--dataflow_base_path=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/", "--region=us-east1" ],
              "image": "dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/healthchecker:20200109-14-rc00",
              "imagePullPolicy": "Never",
              "name": "healthchecker",
              "volumeMounts": [ {
                "mountPath": "/var/log/dataflow",
                "name": "dataflowlogs-healthchecker"
              } ]
            } ],
            "hostNetwork": true,
            "volumes": [ {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/lib/agent/libshuffle_v1.so"
              },
              "name": "shuffle-lib-v1-python"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/lib/agent/libshuffle_v1_py3.so"
              },
              "name": "shuffle-lib-v1-python3"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/opt/google/dataflow"
              },
              "name": "persist"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/log/dataflow/taskrunner/harness"
              },
              "name": "dataflowlogs-harness"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/opt/dataflow/shuffle"
              },
              "name": "dataflow-shuffle"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/log/dataflow/shuffle"
              },
              "name": "dataflowlogs-shuffle"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/log/dataflow/vm_monitor"
              },
              "name": "dataflowlogs-vmmonitor"
            }, {
              "hostPath": {
                "path": "/var/log/dataflow/health_checker"
              },
              "name": "dataflowlogs-healthchecker"
            } ]
          }
        }
      job_name: JOB_NAME
      packages: gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/pickled_main_session|pickled_main_session|gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/dataflow_python_sdk.tar|dataflow_python_sdk.tar|gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/apache_beam-2.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl|apache_beam-2.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
      sdk_pipeline_options: "{\"display_data\":[{\"key\":\"runner\",\"namespace\"\
        :\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"DataflowRunner\"},{\"key\":\"project\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"PROJECT_NAME\"},{\"key\":\"job_name\",\"namespace\"\
        :\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176\"},{\"key\":\"staging_location\"\
        ,\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"\
        type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259\"\
        },{\"key\":\"temp_location\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"gs://TMPBUCKET/temp/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259\"\
        },{\"key\":\"region\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"us-east1\"},{\"key\":\"template_location\"\
        ,\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"\
        type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME\"\
        },{\"key\":\"max_num_workers\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"INTEGER\",\"value\":36},{\"key\":\"machine_type\",\"namespace\"\
        :\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"n1-custom-2-13312\"},{\"key\":\"use_public_ips\",\"namespace\"\
        :\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"BOOLEAN\"\
        ,\"value\":false},{\"key\":\"experiments\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"['use_fastavro']\"},{\"key\":\"beam_plugins\"\
        ,\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"\
        type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"['apache_beam.io.filesystem.FileSystem', 'apache_beam.io.hadoopfilesystem.HadoopFileSystem',\
        \ 'apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.LocalFileSystem', 'apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem']\"\
        },{\"key\":\"save_main_session\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"BOOLEAN\",\"value\":true},{\"key\":\"input\",\"namespace\":\"\
        apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value:\
        \ None)\"},{\"key\":\"output\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: output, type:\
        \ str, default_value: None)\"},{\"key\":\"data4\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: data4, type:\
        \ str, default_value: None)\"},{\"key\":\"data3\",\"namespace\":\"\
        apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: data3, type: str, default_value:\
        \ None)\"},{\"key\":\"data2\",\"namespace\":\"apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: data2, type:\
        \ str, default_value: None)\"},{\"key\":\"data1\",\"namespace\":\"\
        apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions\",\"type\":\"STRING\"\
        ,\"value\":\"RuntimeValueProvider(option: data1, type: str, default_value:\
        \ None)\"},{\"key\":\"templateLocation\",\"namespace\":\"google.dataflow.v1beta3.TemplatesService\"\
        ,\"type\":\"STRING\",\"value\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME\"\
        }],\"options\":{\"data3\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/FILENAME.json.b2\"\
        ,\"data2\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/FILENAME.json.b2\",\"autoscalingAlgorithm\"\
        :\"NONE\",\"beam_plugins\":[\"apache_beam.io.filesystem.FileSystem\",\"apache_beam.io.hadoopfilesystem.HadoopFileSystem\"\
        ,\"apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.LocalFileSystem\",\"apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem.GCSFileSystem\"\
        ],\"dataflowJobId\":\"2020-01-28_05_00_18-6144993012916173105\",\"dataflow_endpoint\"\
        :\"https://dataflow.googleapis.com\",\"direct_num_workers\":1,\"direct_runner_bundle_repeat\"\
        :0,\"direct_runner_use_stacked_bundle\":true,\"dry_run\":false,\"enable_streaming_engine\"\
        :false,\"environment_cache_millis\":0,\"experiments\":[\"use_fastavro\"],\"\
        gcpTempLocation\":\"gs://dataflow-staging-us-east1-657091687220/temp\",\"\
        input\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/input.json\",\"job_name\":\"beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176\"\
        ,\"machine_type\":\"n1-custom-2-13312\",\"data1\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/FILENAME.json.b2\"\
        ,\"maxNumWorkers\":36,\"max_num_workers\":36,\"no_auth\":false,\"numWorkers\"\
        :3,\"output\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/outputs/qout.json\",\"pipelineUrl\":\"\
        gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/pipeline.pb\"\
        ,\"pipeline_type_check\":true,\"profile_cpu\":false,\"profile_memory\":false,\"\
        profile_sample_rate\":1,\"project\":\"PROJECT_NAME\",\"data4\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/FILENAME.json.b2\"\
        ,\"region\":\"us-east1\",\"runner\":\"DataflowRunner\",\"runtime_type_check\"\
        :false,\"save_main_session\":true,\"sdk_location\":\"default\",\"sdk_worker_parallelism\"\
        :0,\"staging_location\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259\"\
        ,\"streaming\":false,\"temp_location\":\"gs://TMPBUCKET/temp/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259\"\
        ,\"templateLocation\":\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME\",\"template_location\"\
        :\"gs://MYBUCKET/dataflow/templates/JOBNAME\",\"type_check_strictness\"\
        :\"DEFAULT_TO_ANY\",\"update\":false,\"use_public_ips\":false}}"
      shutdown-script: |-
        #!/bin/bash 
         sudo /var/lib/agent/shutdown --dataflow_base_path=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/ --region=us-east1
      user-data: |
        #cloud-config


        bootcmd:
        - mount --bind /mnt/stateful_partition/var/lib/agent /var/lib/agent
        - mount -o remount,rw,exec /var/lib/agent
        - iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4194 -j ACCEPT
        - iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
        - iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT
        - iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12346 -j ACCEPT
        - iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12347 -j ACCEPT
        - mkdir -p /etc/systemd/network/99-virtio.network.d
        - echo -e "[Network]\nDHCP=yes\nIPv6AcceptRA=yes" >  /etc/systemd/network/99-virtio.network.d/ipv6.conf
        - systemctl restart systemd-networkd
        - sysctl -w net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh=196608
        - sysctl -w net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh=262144
        runcmd:
        - sudo /bin/bash /var/lib/nvidia/setup_gpu.sh
        - systemctl start agent.service
        - systemctl start kubelet.service
        - systemctl start resource.service
        - sed "s/^/[PARTITION INFO]\t/" /proc/partitions
        - df -h | sed "s/^/[FILESYSTEM INFO]\t/"
        write_files:
        -
          content: |
           [Unit]
           Description=Start kubelet
           Wants=network-online.target
           After=docker.socket network-online.target

           [Service]
           ExecStartPre=/var/lib/agent/boot_checker --endpoint=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/ --region=us-east1
           ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
           ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet --host-network-sources=* --manifest-url=http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/google-container-manifest --manifest-url-header=Metadata-Flavor:Google --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --eviction-hard="" --image-gc-high-threshold=100
           Restart=always
           RestartSec=20

          owner: root
          path: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
          permission: 0644
        -
          content: |
           [Unit]
           Description=Start Dataflow host agent
           Wants=network-online.target
           After=network-online.target

           [Service]
           ExecStart=/var/lib/agent/agent --endpoint=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/ --region=us-east1
           Restart=always
           RestartSec=20

          owner: root
          path: /etc/systemd/system/agent.service
          permission: 0644
        -
          content: |
           [Unit]
           Description=Start Dataflow resource capture agent
           Wants=network-online.target
           After=network-online.target

           [Service]
           ExecStart=/var/lib/agent/resource_capture --endpoint=https://dataflow.googleapis.com/ --region=us-east1
           Restart=always
           RestartSec=20

          owner: root
          path: /etc/systemd/system/resource.service
          permission: 0644
    network: default
    numWorkers: 2
    onHostMaintenance: MIGRATE
    packages:
    - location: storage.googleapis.com/MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/pickled_main_session
      name: pickled_main_session
    - location: storage.googleapis.com/MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/dataflow_python_sdk.tar
      name: dataflow_python_sdk.tar
    - location: storage.googleapis.com/MYBUCKET/dataflow/staging/beamapp-lorenzo-0128125622-520176.1580216182.520259/apache_beam-2.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
      name: apache_beam-2.16.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
    poolArgs: {}
    teardownPolicy: TEARDOWN_ALWAYS
    workerHarnessContainerImage: gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python36:2.16.0
    zone: us-east1-d
id: 2020-01-28_05_00_18-6144993012916173105
location: us-east1
name: JOB_NAME
state: Cancelled
stateTime: '2020-01-28 13:03:11'
type: Batch
```

Comment: What is the error? It might not be related to the temp bucket; however, you can try setting again explicitly the [temp_location as PipelineOption](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options) when executing the template

Comment: I re-checked and the error are actually three, so I created a pastebin because the stacktraces are too long for stackoverflow.
https://pastebin.com/ZUJuWMMU

Comment: @Tlaquetzal I really think it is related btw, because the job completes when I use a small test input.
I suspect that's because when a longer job takes place the temp bucket gets deleted before the job completes

Comment: Even when I set temp_location like this: `pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = "gs://BUCKET/temp"
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:` the problem persists.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough info to figure out what the issue is. Could you elaborate on what the pipeline does? - and if not, please file a support ticket with Dataflow

Comment: @Pablo The pipeline is quite simple: It reads 4 bzip2 files and manipulates their content and then sends it as sideinput to a Map function that iterates through and input json file and adds metadata to each input record using the sideinputs.
Are you sure what I gave you is not already enough?
There is a pastebin with all three stacktraces I got, I'll repost it here: [link](https://pastebin.com/ZUJuWMMU) . Additionally I gave you the command I used to generate and launch the template, plus the full dump of the job environment.
Let me know If there is something I missed there

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the runner needs a staging location (for various pipeline/job files), [that according to docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options#java_3), should default to temp-location if not specified. However it doesn't work that way. You can specify staging-location AND temp-location (you've only specified gcs-location which I don't even see in docs) via cli/options to resolve this issue.

```
--staging-location gs://bucket/path
```

or

```
pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = "gs://bucket/path"
```