# Dataflow job always creates new default bucket even when tempLocation and gcpTempLocation are set?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow job seems to always create a new Default Google Cloud Storage bucket even with stagingLocation, tempLocation, and gcpTempLocation defined. After looking through the Apache Beam (2.6.0) library code, these lines in GcpOptions.java appear to be the culprit:

```
String tempLocation = options.getTempLocation();
  if (isNullOrEmpty(tempLocation)) {
    tempLocation =
        tryCreateDefaultBucket(
            options,
            newCloudResourceManagerClient(options.as(CloudResourceManagerOptions.class))
                .build());
    options.setTempLocation(tempLocation);
  }
```

However, this code should only be executed in the event that tempLocation is not defined in PipelineOptions, and I have set tempLocation both using the command line argument as well as using the setTempLocation method. I have defined the Options interface by extending GcpOptions and adding a few additional option getters and setters.

If I don't define the tempLocation getter and setter in the Options interface it appears as though the tempLocation will automatically default to the newly created default bucket's temp folder (gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-job_number/temp), yet I have defined the tempLocation command line argument.

Here is the main method of the Dataflow job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(Options.class);
    GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/credentials.json"))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    options.setGcpCredential(credentials);
    options.setTempLocation("gs://example_bucket/temp");
    options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://example_bucket/temp");
    run(options);
}
```

Can anyone explain why the default bucket is always created and how I can avoid this?

**Edit:**

It looks as though if I deploy the Dataflow job directly from the command line with the same arguments instead of generating the Dataflow template and then deploying the job through the console interface the tempLocation seems to be set correctly and no additional bucket is created. This seems to resolve the issue I am having but I am not fully sure why this solution works.

Comment: Did you try also to supply [DataflowPipelineOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineOptions.html) interface for pipeline options?

Comment: @mk_sta I just tried extending DataflowPipelineOptions in the Options.class interface but the same issue seems to occur. I originally extended GcpOptions instead. If I don't define the tempLocation getter and setter in the Options interface it appears as though the tempLocation will automatically default to the newly created default bucket's temp folder (gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-job_number/temp)

Comment: Let me do some basic troubleshooting. Can you confirm that the bucket you're setting as the temp location has already been created? Can you confirm that you're supplying the options to the Pipeline like so: `Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);`?

Comment: @Daniel Oliveira I can confirm that the bucket I am setting as the tempLocation is already existing on Google Cloud Storage. I am also supplying the options to the Pipeline using the code you included inside of the run method.  After observing the generated template file, I can also see that both options are correctly set in the template's PipelineOptions. After deploying the Dataflow job using the online Google Cloud interface however, the default gcpTempLocation is still created. I have included a new edit in my original post as my issue has been solved, but the solution confuses me.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this behavior for particular [PipelineOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options) is well explained in  GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service):

> **gcpTempLocation** - A Cloud Storage path for Dataflow to stage any temporary files. You must create this bucket ahead of time, before
>   running your pipeline. In case you don't specify `gcpTempLocation`,
>   you can specify the pipeline option `tempLocation` and then
>   `gcpTempLocation` will be set to the value of `tempLocation`. **If
>   neither are specified, a default `gcpTempLocation` will be created.**

So far, it seems to be the hard coded case for GCP Dataflow managed services.

Comment: The default location seems to be created even when I specify the tempLocation and gcpTempLocation via both the command line arguments as well as in the code itself however, so this behavior shouldn't be expected right?

Comment: As per documentation lines: A default **gcpTempLocation** will be created if neither it nor **tempLocation** is specified.

Comment: I see that, but the issue I am having is that the default gcpTempLocation is being created despite me specifying the tempLocation and gcpTempLocation explicitly in both the command line arguments and programatically (using the setters for tempLocation and gcpTempLocation on the PipelineOptions). After observing the generated template file, I can also see that both options are correctly set in the template's PipelineOptions. After deploying the Dataflow job using the online Google Cloud interface however, the default gcpTempLocation is still created.

Comment: I've just seen you've edited the answer, in this situation I would encourage to use [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) and report this kind of bug.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket being created is for staging location, which is supposed to default to temp location, but it's broken (as of SDK v2.43.0).
You can specify your staging location to avoid creating the extra bucket.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403319/1031796